# Is there a better way or ajax control (for Calendar)

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need a calendar to be displayed on a textbox.

> This can be achieved using ajaxToolkit: Calendar control.
>
> I can use FilteredTextBoxExtender to ensure that it enters only valid characters.
>
> Also I can use jQuery to ensure that the dates are valid dates only (13/13/20123 is an invalid date).

But is there a better way or ajax control (in the toolkit) for it?

Note: I am looking for a solution using ajax control toolkit. For my project, jQuery-UI is not allowed.

```
<ajaxToolkit:Calendar runat="server"
TargetControlID="Date1"
CssClass="ClassName"
Format="MMMM d, yyyy"
PopupButtonID="Image1" />


<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbe" runat="server"
TargetControlID="txtDate"         
FilterType="Custom, Numbers"
ValidChars="1234567890/" />
```

REFERENCE:

1. http://forums.asp.net/p/1825929/5076051.aspx/1?Re+How+to+disable+future+dates+in+ajax+calendar+extender+

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is wrong with what you have suggested?

Comment: @KevinMain I am trying to avoid the javascript/jQuery validation part in such a way that this can be achieved through a property of the control

Comment: Think you might be out of luck then as I am pretty sure this is not built into the control - you can easily check yourself as it is open source (here http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) - you could probably fork the code and add the functionality yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try Using jQuery UI Datepicker:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>

<div class="demo">
   <p>Date: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>
</div>
```

[jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: I am looking for a solution using ajax control toolkit. For my project, jQuery-UI is not allowed.